# Android Studio logcat emulator automatically changes to a [DISCONNECTED] version

Tags: android, android-studio, android-emulator

Does anyone also have the problem where when you run an app in an emulator the logcat automatically changes the selected emulator to a [DISCONNECTED] version?

It has been happening to me for a while now and I've never been able to solve it.

It is not every time that it happens, but when it does the behavior persists. It's annoying because you have to select the non [DISCONNECTED] version every time to check the logs.

[image]

How can one fix it?

---

Additional info:

- Ubuntu 20.04.4 LTS
- Android Studio Bumble Bee 2021.1.1 Patch 1

Comment: Did you find any solution ? Same problem here.

Comment: @NinoDELCEY, not yet =/. Do you also use Ubuntu?

Comment: No, Windows ...

Comment: Same here (Win10, 2021.2.1 Chipmunk)